# Register entire domain as relying party trust in ADFS2 using SAML2?

Tags: single-sign-on, adfs2.0, saml-2.0

I'm having an issue with SAML2 in ADFS2 that I didn't experience when using WS-Fed in ADFS2.  When originally using WS-Fed, I set up a relying party trust as, for example `https://www.example.com/`,
Within my app, we'd often need to re-authenticate and I'd send up (wtrealm) URLs like `https://www.example.com/home.aspx` or `https://www.example.com/someOtherPage.aspx`.  I'd always be re-authenticated are redirected back to whichever page I sent up as the wtrealm, making it seem like having `https://www.example.com/` as my only relying party trust was enough.  Now it seems with SAML2, I need to explicitly set up a relying party trust for every single possible URL that may be sent up.  It even appears to be CASE sensitive.  How can this be?  Am I missing something?  If this were the case, how could any URL with an unpredictable query string ever work?

Comment: What are you using to connect the ASP.NET application to ADFS using SAML?

Comment: Custom code that uses the UltimateSaml component for .NET.

Comment: You need a single url - Assertion Consumer Service (ACS) url through which all communications will flow. I have learnt it the hard way, and yes it is indeed case sensitive. SAML uses the concept of RelayState so the communication would happen via example.com/sso.aspx and the relaystate would be '/home.aspx' or '/somepath/someotherpage.aspx'